# How to do canonical url at blog plugin?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

What I need to write in the url field for the Blog OctoberCMS plugin to generate canonical URLS of type site.tu/some-category/post-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `/:category?/:slug?` in the url area of the page that hosts the blog post.

[image]